# VirtualBox Linux - Hard drive not showing correct amount of space

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox

I recently changed the amount of space of the VDI using `VBoxManage modifyhd` from 8 GB to 20 GB. I've checked it and it says only 6.6 GB, and now I'm running out of space. It might have been like that before, but I'm not sure. I tried adding another hard drive, but it's not showing either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize the root partition.

Though I don't know the distribution you are running, I think these steps in the first answer will work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime

You can also run a linux live .iso in your virtualbox, and use gparted to resize the root partition.

Comment: Or, more precisely: You can expand whatever partition is last on the virtual disk. Everything else would require you to move whole partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that extending the VDI only shows up in fdisk -l output, as that is just a partition resize. The filesystem needs to be resized too, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If another hard disk/SSD with appropriate size is available you can export appliance and import it to new location. After this increasing imported VDI size is recognized by gparted.

This avoids resizing all snapshots as well as keeps prior VM version intact.